# Powerpoint VBA: is it possible to enable user to select range in Excel using a mouse/keyboard?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, selection

In excel, you can have a user dynamically select a range of cells by selecting it with his/her mouse or keyboard (e.g., picture below, or simply when you're typing up a formula on ENTER mode and proceed to select a range of cells):

[image]
Does anyone know if such a functionality is callable from a Powerpoint macro/add-in? Essentially, I would like to have a piece of code in Powerpoint that generates a similar dialogue that allows a user to directly select a range of cells in an excel spreadsheet, and have the PPT macro record what that range is.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this in Windows (dialog title bar suggests yes) or on Mac? Does it have to be cross platform compatible?

Comment: This is in windows. Not sure what you mean by cross-platform compatible...? Just need it to work between ppt and excel, within Windows 7.

I've tried below code in PPT, but it doesn't work (might work in Excel but need the dialogue to originate in PPT since this is a PPT macro)
Set ExcelRange = Excel.application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range with your Mouse to be bolded.", Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)

Comment: Perhaps you can show how you are calling the above from within Powerpoint (edit your question don't add code in comments). Also I recommend looking at the links on the right `--->` ; "Open Excel file in VBA from Powerpoint" has some helpful pointers, for instance.

Comment: Yes it is possible but for that you have to hook on to existing Excel application.

Comment: or if there is no excel opened then, create a new one and work with that instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example you using `GetObject`

**Note**: The `Application.InputBox` opens modally. You cannot use it across workbooks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAddressFromExcel()
    Dim oXLApp As Object
    Dim Ret As Object

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    If oXLApp.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
        oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = oXLApp.InputBox("Please select Excel Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then MsgBox Ret.Address

    '~~> CLEANUP
    oXLApp.Quit
    Set oXLApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! Thanks Siddharth! I think the reason my original code didn't work was that it did not use the GetObject method and instead had a CreateObject. This is awesome!

Comment: You can use createobject but only use it if there is no other instance of excel open.

Comment: Not sure if you'll see this comment, but do you know if there is a way to return the sheet name or number of whichever cell range the user chooses through this inputbox? The inputbox should return the address in the format of "A1:B2" or something, but any idea if it's possible to return also which sheet the cell range is in?

Comment: `MsgBox Ret.Parent.Name` will give you the sheet name :)